# Magento Upgrade from 1.9.4.5 to Openmage 20.x

Tags: php, magento, composer-php, magento-1.9

I need to upgrade my Magento 1.9.4.5 site to Openmage 20.x

I followed the guides https://www.openmage.org/magento-lts/migration-guide.html for the migration or the guide in https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts to install it with composer but I'm not understanding what is the best / cleaner method to do this update.

I did this:

- I downloaded the openmage 20.x zip and unzipped it in my Magento 1.9.4.5 root folder
- I changed the php version to 8.0
- I updated all the various functions of the plugins and of my custom theme that weren't compatible with php 8.0

So now my site work correctly with Openmage version 20.x and PHP 8.0

But now, I'm not sure if update flow, is correct.

For example, I've read here: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts that Between Magento 1.9.4.5 and OpenMage 19.x there are some removed modules: Mage_Backup (#2811), Mage_Compiler, Mage_GoogleBase, Mage_PageCache (#2258), Mage_Xmlconnect, Phoenix_Moneybookers.
but I still have these modules active in my installation because I have only overwritten the files and folders.

So i have two questions:

1. Now i need to remove manually this modules?
2. How i can understand if there are some others modules removed by Openmage 20.x?

Comment: "I'm not sure if this is correct though" - how should anybody else know that? Why not test whether everything works or not?

Comment: Thank you for your raply. I think my english is not good and i explained myself badly.
My site works and i currently use Openmage 20.x with PHP 8 without any problem.
I just want to know if there is a "cleaner" way to upgrade from Magento 1.9.x to Openmage because i think that this is not a good way.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: _"I've read that with Openmage, for example, Mage_xxx modules have been deleted..."_  please provide reference for this. Don't use placeholders but the complete names and reference where you have read about that for each module.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice! I corrected my question and made it more specific.

Comment: And what prevents you following the linked instructions for those modules if you have them still in use?

Comment: What I would like to understand is if someone who uses openmage, recommends me to remove these modules manually since they are no longer supported by openmage. So it'is better to remove for example: Mage_GoogleBase or Mage_Backup modules?

Comment: How should persons who use Openmage but don't know you nor your project give you recommendations? How is Stackoverflow a recommendation platform? Please stick on topic and ask answerable questions in scope of the site. In general, modules you don't use, you should remove from the software configuration, this is both true for maintained and unmaintained code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenMage is actively maintained, the code base is constantly being updated for bugs, security, and PHP compatibility; for ver 20.x, new features.

Answer 1: as you have discovered, OpenMage works when you migrate by overwriting the existing code with ver20. There is no need to remove unused or deprecated modules. It is fine to keep the old modules. It is also fine to remove them, which you have to do manually. Take `Mage_Backup` as an example, the following files and folders can be removed:

1. `app\etc\modules\Mage_Backup`
2. `app\code\core\Mage\Backup\`
3. `app\locale\en_US\Mage_Backup.csv`
4. `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Backup\`
5. `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\backup\`
6. `lib\Mage\Backup.php`
7. `lib\Mage\Backup\`

For other modules, the tables in the database can be removed.

IMHO, I **do not** recommend removing the modules if you have no experience in developing OpenMage.

Answer 2: To know which modules are removed, read the doc [here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/#changes)

Comment: This was exactly the confirmation I wanted :)
I wanted to understand how Openmage works with "no longer supported" modules.
Thanks for your time and explanation